# How to make DEL in isearch always delete character?

Tags: key-bindings, isearch

In Isearch, after hitting `C-s` a few times, you have to hit `DEL` a few times to get back to editing the search string.

How can I disable this behavior? I'd like it so that `DEL` always deletes a character from the search string (the behavior of `DEL` when you've hit `C-s` just once [to activate Isearch initially]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key `C-M-w` does what you are asking for. It is bound in `isearch-mode-map` to `isearch-del-char`, while `DEL` is bound to `isearch-delete-char`.

If you really want `DEL` to be bound to `isearch-del-char` then just bind it:

```el
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "DEL") 'isearch-del-char)
```

Similarly, you could bind `C-M-w` to `isearch-delete-char`, if you wanted to:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-M-w") 'isearch-delete-char)
```

You can find out which keys are bound to which commands in `isearch-mode-map` or any other keymap using `C-h M-k` (`describe-keymap`), if you use library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el).